# How to scale div with the image dimension?

Tags: css

I'm creating a JS slider for before and after of the images. I have the following HTML, JS and CSS:

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>


<div class="mainSection">

    <div id="one" class="bal-container">
        <div class="bal-after">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UhD5VoC.png">
            <div class="bal-afterPosition afterLabel">
                After
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bal-before">
            <div class="bal-before-inset">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lQRgFqb.png">
                <div class="bal-beforePosition beforeLabel">
                    Before
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bal-handle">
            <span class=" handle-left-arrow"></span>
            <span class="handle-right-arrow"></span>
        </div>

    </div>

    
</div>


<script>
class BeforeAfter {
    constructor(enteryObject) {

        const beforeAfterContainer = document.querySelector(enteryObject.id);
        const before = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-before');
        const beforeText = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-beforePosition');
        const afterText = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-afterPosition');
        const handle = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-handle');
        var widthChange = 0;

        beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-before-inset').setAttribute("style", "width: " + beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth + "px;")
        window.onresize = function () {
            beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-before-inset').setAttribute("style", "width: " + beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth + "px;")
        }
        before.setAttribute('style', "width: 50%;");
        handle.setAttribute('style', "left: 50%;");

        //touch screen event listener
        beforeAfterContainer.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {

            beforeAfterContainer.addEventListener("touchmove", (e2) => {
                let containerWidth = beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth;
                let currentPoint = e2.changedTouches[0].clientX;

                let startOfDiv = beforeAfterContainer.offsetLeft;

                let modifiedCurrentPoint = currentPoint - startOfDiv;

                if (modifiedCurrentPoint > 10 && modifiedCurrentPoint < beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth - 10) {
                    let newWidth = modifiedCurrentPoint * 100 / containerWidth;

                    before.setAttribute('style', "width:" + newWidth + "%;");
                    afterText.setAttribute('style', "z-index: 1;");
                    handle.setAttribute('style', "left:" + newWidth + "%;");
                }
            });
        });

        //mouse move event listener
        beforeAfterContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            let containerWidth = beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth;
            widthChange = e.offsetX;
            let newWidth = widthChange * 100 / containerWidth;

            if (e.offsetX > 10 && e.offsetX < beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth - 10) {
                before.setAttribute('style', "width:" + newWidth + "%;");
                afterText.setAttribute('style', "z-index:" + "1;");
                handle.setAttribute('style', "left:" + newWidth + "%;");
            }
        })

    }
}

</script>

<script>
    new BeforeAfter({
        id: '#one'
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
@media all and (max-width: 479px) {
    .mainSection {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: stretch;
        align-content: stretch;
        width: 100%;
        height: 700px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .bal-container {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 599px) {
    .mainSection {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: stretch;
        align-content: stretch;
        width: 100%;
        height: 800px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .bal-container {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .mainSection {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: stretch;
        align-content: stretch;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1000px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .bal-container {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    .mainSection {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: stretch;
        align-content: stretch;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1100px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .bal-container {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .mainSection {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: stretch;
        align-content: stretch;
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .bal-container {
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1199px) {
    .mainSection {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: stretch;
        align-content: stretch;
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .bal-container {
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
}

/* Before After Container */ 
.bal-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: grab;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.bal-after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bal-before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    /* right: 0; */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 15;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bal-before-inset {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.bal-after img,
.bal-before img {
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.bal-beforePosition {
    background: #121212;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}

.bal-afterPosition {
    background: #121212;
    color: #fff;
    right: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}

.beforeLabel {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 1rem;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.afterLabel {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 1rem;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* handle and arrow */
.bal-handle {
    height: 41px;
    width: 41px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: -21px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    z-index: 20;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(12, 12, 12);
}

.handle-left-arrow,
.handle-right-arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 6px inset transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
}

.handle-left-arrow {
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -17px;
}

.handle-right-arrow {
    border-left: 6px solid #fff;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -17px;
}

.bal-handle::before {
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(12, 12, 12);
}

.bal-handle::after {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 20.5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(12, 12, 12);
}

.bal-handle::before,
.bal-handle::after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 9999px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
}
```

The problem is that what I have at the moment zooms on the images and the images are not fully visible. For example, I use the following two images which are about 587x600 in dimension: https://imgur.com/a/YDdaZYR

Any ideas how to make sure that the `mainSection` div adjusts itself according to the images to make them fully visible (it is okay if the images are scaled down to certain dimension as long as they fully fit and are nice looking).

Comment: i think the example in w3 website can help you    https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: @mohammad I'm doing a before/after slider, so is different than what that example does. Also in that example the dimension of the pictures are fixed, and is not adaptive. Here somehow I need the slider container to adapt based on the size of the images.

Comment: @mohammad congratulations, you found exactly the pattern of how not to build a slideshow. w3schools is all but not a reliable website with leigitimate code examples, best practices, and it's not community driven.

Comment: @terett have you tried flex-wrap:wrap ? i think this will resolve the issue

Comment: @mohammad That doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak around with the `object-fit` of the `.bal-after img` & `.bal-before img` to be `contain` instead of `cover`, and then adjust the `height` of the container, accordingly. Somehow, like this:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 479px) {
  .mainSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .bal-container {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 599px) {
  .mainSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .bal-container {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .mainSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px; /*was 1000px*/
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .bal-container {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  .mainSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1100px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .bal-container {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .mainSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .bal-container {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1199px) {
  .mainSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .bal-container {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
}


/* Before After Container */

.bal-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: grab;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.bal-after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bal-before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /* right: 0; */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 15;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bal-before-inset {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.bal-after img,
.bal-before img {
  object-fit: contain; /*was cover*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.bal-beforePosition {
  background: #121212;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.bal-afterPosition {
  background: #121212;
  color: #fff;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.beforeLabel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.afterLabel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* handle and arrow */

.bal-handle {
  height: 41px;
  width: 41px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -21px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  z-index: 20;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(12, 12, 12);
}

.handle-left-arrow,
.handle-right-arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px inset transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.handle-left-arrow {
  border-right: 6px solid #fff;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -17px;
}

.handle-right-arrow {
  border-left: 6px solid #fff;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -17px;
}

.bal-handle::before {
  bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(12, 12, 12);
}

.bal-handle::after {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 20.5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(12, 12, 12);
}

.bal-handle::before,
.bal-handle::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 9999px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1.5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="mainSection">

    <div id="one" class="bal-container">
      <div class="bal-after">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UhD5VoC.png">
        <div class="bal-afterPosition afterLabel">
          After
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bal-before">
        <div class="bal-before-inset">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lQRgFqb.png">
          <div class="bal-beforePosition beforeLabel">
            Before
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bal-handle">
        <span class=" handle-left-arrow"></span>
        <span class="handle-right-arrow"></span>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>


  <script>
    class BeforeAfter {
      constructor(enteryObject) {

        const beforeAfterContainer = document.querySelector(enteryObject.id);
        const before = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-before');
        const beforeText = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-beforePosition');
        const afterText = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-afterPosition');
        const handle = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-handle');
        var widthChange = 0;

        beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-before-inset').setAttribute("style", "width: " + beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth + "px;")
        window.onresize = function() {
          beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-before-inset').setAttribute("style", "width: " + beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth + "px;")
        }
        before.setAttribute('style', "width: 50%;");
        handle.setAttribute('style', "left: 50%;");

        //touch screen event listener
        beforeAfterContainer.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {

          beforeAfterContainer.addEventListener("touchmove", (e2) => {
            let containerWidth = beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth;
            let currentPoint = e2.changedTouches[0].clientX;

            let startOfDiv = beforeAfterContainer.offsetLeft;

            let modifiedCurrentPoint = currentPoint - startOfDiv;

            if (modifiedCurrentPoint > 10 && modifiedCurrentPoint < beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth - 10) {
              let newWidth = modifiedCurrentPoint * 100 / containerWidth;

              before.setAttribute('style', "width:" + newWidth + "%;");
              afterText.setAttribute('style', "z-index: 1;");
              handle.setAttribute('style', "left:" + newWidth + "%;");
            }
          });
        });

        //mouse move event listener
        beforeAfterContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
          let containerWidth = beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth;
          widthChange = e.offsetX;
          let newWidth = widthChange * 100 / containerWidth;

          if (e.offsetX > 10 && e.offsetX < beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth - 10) {
            before.setAttribute('style', "width:" + newWidth + "%;");
            afterText.setAttribute('style', "z-index:" + "1;");
            handle.setAttribute('style', "left:" + newWidth + "%;");
          }
        })

      }
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    new BeforeAfter({
      id: '#one'
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to resize the `mainSection` according to the size of the images, here, I am tracking the height and width of the first image and setting these values to the `mainSection`. Works as you wanted.

```js
class BeforeAfter {
  constructor(enteryObject) {

    const beforeAfterContainer = document.querySelector(enteryObject.id);
    const before = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-before');
    const beforeText = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-beforePosition');
    const afterText = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-afterPosition');
    const handle = beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-handle');
    var widthChange = 0;

    beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-before-inset').setAttribute("style", "width: " + beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth + "px;")
    window.onresize = function() {
      beforeAfterContainer.querySelector('.bal-before-inset').setAttribute("style", "width: " + beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth + "px;")
    }
    before.setAttribute('style', "width: 50%;");
    handle.setAttribute('style', "left: 50%;");

    //touch screen event listener
    beforeAfterContainer.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {

      beforeAfterContainer.addEventListener("touchmove", (e2) => {
        let containerWidth = beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth;
        let currentPoint = e2.changedTouches[0].clientX;

        let startOfDiv = beforeAfterContainer.offsetLeft;

        let modifiedCurrentPoint = currentPoint - startOfDiv;

        if (modifiedCurrentPoint > 10 && modifiedCurrentPoint < beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth - 10) {
          let newWidth = modifiedCurrentPoint * 100 / containerWidth;

          before.setAttribute('style', "width:" + newWidth + "%;");
          afterText.setAttribute('style', "z-index: 1;");
          handle.setAttribute('style', "left:" + newWidth + "%;");
        }
      });
    });

    //mouse move event listener
    beforeAfterContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      let containerWidth = beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth;
      widthChange = e.offsetX;
      let newWidth = widthChange * 100 / containerWidth;

      if (e.offsetX > 10 && e.offsetX < beforeAfterContainer.offsetWidth - 10) {
        before.setAttribute('style', "width:" + newWidth + "%;");
        afterText.setAttribute('style', "z-index:" + "1;");
        handle.setAttribute('style', "left:" + newWidth + "%;");
      }
    })

  }
}


new BeforeAfter({
  id: '#one'
});

let imgW = document.getElementsByClassName("bal-after")[0].children[0].offsetWidth;
let imgH = document.getElementsByClassName("bal-after")[0].children[0].offsetHeight;
let widthMain = document.getElementById("mainS");
document.getElementById("mainS").style.maxWidth = imgW + "px";
document.getElementById("mainS").style.maxHeight = imgH + "px";
```

```css
@media all and (max-width: 479px) {
  .mainSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .bal-container {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 599px) {
  .mainSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .bal-container {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .mainSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .bal-container {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  .mainSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1100px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .bal-container {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .mainSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .bal-container {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1199px) {
  .mainSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .bal-container {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
}


/* Before After Container */

.bal-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: grab;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.bal-after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bal-before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /* right: 0; */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 15;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bal-before-inset {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.bal-after img,
.bal-before img {
  object-fit: contain;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.bal-beforePosition {
  background: #121212;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.bal-afterPosition {
  background: #121212;
  color: #fff;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.beforeLabel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.afterLabel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* handle and arrow */

.bal-handle {
  height: 41px;
  width: 41px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -21px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  z-index: 20;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(12, 12, 12);
}

.handle-left-arrow,
.handle-right-arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px inset transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.handle-left-arrow {
  border-right: 6px solid #fff;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -17px;
}

.handle-right-arrow {
  border-left: 6px solid #fff;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -17px;
}

.bal-handle::before {
  bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(12, 12, 12);
}

.bal-handle::after {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 20.5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(12, 12, 12);
}

.bal-handle::before,
.bal-handle::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 9999px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1.5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div id="mainS" class="mainSection">

    <div id="one" class="bal-container">
      <div class="bal-after">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UhD5VoC.png">
        <div class="bal-afterPosition afterLabel">
          After
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bal-before">
        <div class="bal-before-inset">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lQRgFqb.png">
          <div class="bal-beforePosition beforeLabel">
            Before
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bal-handle">
        <span class=" handle-left-arrow"></span>
        <span class="handle-right-arrow"></span>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>




</body>

</html>
```